# Reading in integers

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, greatest-common-divisor

I wrote a GCD function that I know works correctly. However, when I try to make it accept command line args, it doesn't work. What's going on?

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int euclid(int m, int n)
{
    int r = m % n;

    if (r == 0)
        return n;

    return euclid(n, r);
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", euclid(atoi(argv[0]), atoi(argv[1])));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("%d\n", euclid(atoi(argv[0]), atoi(argv[1])));
```

`argv[0]` is the executable name itself. You should use `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`.

Comment: No, you don't need to since you are only printing one argument

Comment: Probably help to check the value of argc as well.   The behaviour will be undefined if argv[1] or argv[2] are NULL.

Comment: @CoolGuy No, only 2. The format string, and the other one returned by `euclid()`.

Comment: Oops. I got confused and thought that the `printf` was :`printf("%d\n", euclid(atoi(argv[0])), atoi(argv[1]));`. My bad